# How to map a Python array into a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mapping

I have an array of arrays:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
data = [[1.0,0.56,1.3,1.0],
        [2.0,0.59,1.3,1.0], 
        [3.0,0.63,1.3,1.0],
        [4.0,0.66,1.3,1.0]]
```

that I'm trying to map into this NumPy form:

```
[[array([ 0.,  1.]), array([ 0.,  0.56]), array([ 0.,  1.3]), array([ 0.,  1.])], [array([ 0.,  2.]), array([ 0.,  0.59]), array([ 0.,  1.3]), array([ 0.,  1.])], [array([ 0.,  3.]), array([ 0.,  0.63]), array([ 0.,  1.3]), array([ 0.,  1.0.])], [array([ 0.,  4.]), array([ 0.,  0.66]), array([ 0.,  1.3]), array([ 0.,  1.])]]
```

I've already tried doing the following:

```
s = Set([])
maxNDimValues = max(map(lambda x: len(s.union(Set(x))), transpose(data)))
valueMap = identity(maxNDimValues).astype(float64)
trainingitems = map(lambda x: map(lambda y: valueMap[y-1], x), data)
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: If `data` is a list of lists, why doesn't `np.array(data)` suffice?

Comment: Why would you want a list of 1-D arrays, rather than a single 2-D array?

Comment: For some reason, when I tried this it printed the array in its original form although I imported numpy as np and array from numpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I think I see what you're trying to do now. From a list of lists, you (for some reason I really don't understand) want a list of lists of array elements, each containing a 0 along with the original item.

The most obvious way (at the cost of a double for-loop) is

```
result = [[np.array([0, x]) for x in row] for row in data]
```

A better thing to do might be to make use of a 3-dimensional numpy array.

```
temp = np.array(data)
temp = np.expand_dims(temp, 2)
result = np.concatenate((np.zeros(temp.shape), temp), axis=2)
```

Comment: The first variant almost screams to be written as a list comprehension, it's just so terse  `[[np.array([0, x]) for x in row] for row in data]`.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you!

Comment: @moarningsun Yes indeed, since I use python mostly only with numpy, I never really took the time off to learn how to write pure python tersely. Edited, as suggested.